# Type of blade shanks for Bosch PST 50 AE

Tags: power-tools, blade, saw-blade, jigsaw

Sorry for my novice question, but I'm looking to buy some blades (for using with wood) for my dads old Bosch PST 50 AE.

[image: Bosch PST 50 AE]

Would just any Bosch blades fit this old Bosch model?

Or has there been (or are there) different type of blade shanks that Bosch uses?

I found these [blades](https://www.clasohlson.com/se/Sticks%C3%A5gsblad-Bosch,-sortiment/p/40-9351) and they are using "T-shanks", would they fit?
[image: Blades]

Has this image anything to do with what type of blade shanks is being used?
[image: Symbol]

Comment: What kind of wood will you cut? Usually better to buy blades for type of cutting needed, instead of generic wood blades in multipack.

Comment: Yeah there's actually a surprising variety of blade types available intended for wood, and it can be important to choose wisely for your intended use. If you're going to mostly cut plywood for example there are blades intended for you to work good side up and good side down (because the blade will chip out the opposite side).

Comment: P.S. I think it's also worth mentioning that some people do deliberately use blades originally designed for other materials when cutting wood and wood products and report good results. A good example is the finer teeth on some metal blades can cut plywood quite well (very slow to cut, but little chipping) and certainly better than many basic wood blades with their honking big teeth.

Comment: @Volfram K - I'm looking to cut out a hole for the sink in a laminated particle (wood chips) board for our laundry room.

Comment: BTW- the circled icon is Bosch's logo. You'll see it on every Bosch product from power tools to spark plugs.

Comment: @VolframK this isn't about blade material or tooth design, but about the blade mounting system. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan ja I know! I ask because of multipack.

Comment: Ola, these blades often recommended for laminate https://www.clasohlson.com/se/Sticks&aring;gsblad-HCS-T101BR-Bosch/p/40-9352-3

Comment: @Volfram K: That blade looks perfect, thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 4):

Although not foolproof, you can generally figure out which style to use in the saw by the way the blade connects to the saw. In general, if you need a tool to change the blade, it's a U-shank. If you can do it without a tool it's a T-shank. There are exceptions, and this looks to be one.

Some especially old jigsaws take a U-shank blade with an additional hole in it, and unless you can modify a new blade to fit, these are becoming much harder to replace.

[image: T, U, and "Universal" blades - https://www.tooled-up.com/blog/choosing-jigsaw-blades/]

A bunch of saws that take T-shank will also run on U-shank too. This is "more true" with newer saws I believe. And in the interest of universal fit, Ryobi (and probably others) make blades that are supposed combine features and work with "any" saw.

Based on the age of the saw, my first thought was that U-shank blades would be the most likely fit, but **looking around the Internet makes me think that that particular model uses T-shank blades or, more likely, either kind of blade.**

There are a couple of current ebay listings for that specific saw which include assorted T-shank blades. That seems to suggest that T-shank is the fit.
[image]

Also, [JDV has shared a link for a YouTube video](https://youtu.be/L68Js3FefCc?t=127) that shows the procedure for changing the blade with a similar Bosch saw model that seems to use T-shank blades and a long screwdriver that came with the saw.

I have also found pictures of the reverse side of the saw which features a label that seems to specify which blades are recommended for different materials.
[image]

Comment: https://youtu.be/L68Js3FefCc?t=127 Looks like it is t-style. It is fastened by a slot or hex head fastener through the hole in the very top.

Comment: @jdv While doing a little research on u vs. t blades one source says that u blades require an external tool such as a screwdriver.  However, in the video the woman is using a t blade so I suspect that this jigsaw will take either style.

Comment: @jdv I'm seeing that there is a long-shafted screwdriver sold as a "spare part" for this saw...which is what the guy in the video is using. I see a bunch of ebay and second-hand tool listings that are also featuring t-shank blades so I'm inclined to change my answer.

Comment: @Ashlar - Yes, it seems that either style would work, I'd guess, but T-shank seems to be the preferred.

Comment: @gnicko, the person in the video looks like a woman, but yes. You need a long-shanked screwdriver to loosen the blade holder deep in the handle, turn the blade 90 degrees, and pull it out. And the video shows a standard t-style, no holes. Not an answer because all I have is that video -- I would have liked to have found the manual.

Comment: My guess is that any t-shank will work. It's just that the hole will not be used here. there is a custom clamping device that holds the blade secure. Not using this clamping device will result in broken blades, tears, and recriminations no doubt.

Comment: @jdv - Yeah, it's a woman. My bad. I think you're right. Any T or U-shank will work I'll bet. I only found one manual specific to that exact saw...but the site wanted money to get to it. I did find 50-A and 50-E manuals available, but who knows how close they are to "50-AE" or that the change from one model to the next isn't the blade "chuck"... From what I can tell, the 50-AE seems to have been popular in Eastern Europe and Germany, etc. so it might just be voltage/power cord differences.

Comment: @gnicko because of the 1/4 turn mechanism, I wonder if the T in the blade slots into something inside to give it a positive lock, and then the "chuck" secures it. I'd stick with any t-style and then you know at least one other person had good luck with that.

Comment: Finally, good catch on the blade types listed on the machine itself. Those are all T-type without any hole.

Comment: Thanks for the input everybody. So I'll buy some T-shank then this weekend and hope for the best.